# Does SQL Server have a way to substitute a different version of a table based on login?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, localization, schema

I'd like to know if there is a way that SQL server can provide a different version of a table based on the database login. For example I'd like to be able to give a different list of items and prices for a given region/locale based on the login.

I realize I can add schema and changes join conditions across the application but this would be a lot of work in updating and testing.

Can this be done by creating different schema such as [en-ca].[items] vs [en-us].[items] or [pt-br].[items] available only in brazil for example?

Comment: Have you tried it?  It should be possible to have the same table name under different schemas in SQL Server.  You could then set the default schema for each user.  Depending on how you connect and query, it should work.

Comment: You could add another column to your table, which will indicate the region. Another approach would be creating table per region. But I think first approach is closest to what you're after.

Comment: You should be able to do what you want using a view(s)

Comment: @Jimbo without changing the application how would I be able to configure a view(S) to hand back the appropriate set of rows ?

Comment: 1. application is currently selecting from table A
2. Rename table a to table x
3. Create view with same name as table A
4. Inside view add logic to check current_user and return appropriate results from table x

Answer (score 2):

You could use Row-Level Security to control which users see which rows. Some links:

[Row-Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security)

[SQL Server 2016 Row Level Security – A Practical Example](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatform/2017/02/17/sql-server-2016-row-level-security-a-practical-example)